# Merge my 2 accounts

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

I was just trying to swap around my Open ID (tossing MyOpenID and adding Google) and ended up creating a 2nd account.  Could someone please merge my 2 accounts?  The ID of my good account is 43, the new one is 10527.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has now been completed. ♪

Comment: @squillman: And you got to keep your elite two-digit user id, too!

Comment: @Brant haha, yeah.  Time to pick up the activity in order to warrant it, methinks!