# One User, Two Accounts

Tags: support, user-accounts

I've just found a user who has more than 1 account:

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/73355/ostarz

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/66739/ostarz

I know it's the same person because of his answer to his own question, which states he's the same user who asked it:

[Battlelog shows I am not Premium even though I've purchased Premium Edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162623/battlelog-not-saying-im-premium-battlefield-3/162764#162764)

I don't think this guy is trying to sock puppet or do anything malicious, but it seems he's having a bit of trouble with accounts. Is there a way for someone to maybe help him out/combine the accounts? (e.g. two accounts merged here: [Merge my 2 accounts](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2414/merge-my-2-accounts))

Comment: A mod should probably point him to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @3ve Why would you need a mod for that? :)

Comment: @badp presumably as we mere users can't get hold of a user directly

Comment: @badp it's pretty hard to contact a user with no posts as a normal user. Commenting on his unregistered account's post is unlikely to get his attention..

Answer (score -7):

The post says 'Questions this Question' not 'Asked this Question'

Not saying its not the same person but this does not look like proof of any sort to me. Odd they both have the same name though eh?

Comment: It could be a non-native English speaker, and that would be a reasonable way of phrasing it if you didn't know better